# How to apply a texture to a certain (specified by coordinates) area of ​an object?

Tags: python, texturing, uv

I want to apply a texture to a certain (specified by coordinates) area of ​​an object. In the picture shown, this area is shaded in blue. The rest of the object will remain without texture.

And although the task is actually more difficult than I described. Since objects can be not only of a simple shape (like a cube), but also a cylinder. But first, I would like to apply a texture to a part of the cube.
[image]
This must be done using python, that is, programmatically. But I suppose that if I know how to do it manually (that is, with a mouse), then I will be able to translate it into code.

At this point, I have managed to programmatically overlay the texture on the WHOLE object as a whole. Using material and creating new material.

However, I have not come close to understanding how to paint over a part of an object (by coordinates) with texture, please tell me.

Comment: Hello, could you add a bit more details about your shader setup ? There are a few ways to do it, vertex colors, procedural textures, or regular bitmap texture with UV coordinates

Comment: Thanks for answering my slightly newbie question.) Its need to make more detailed investigation from my side and I would be found the functionality of Texture projection with use Node-Project.

Comment: Finally, I was used functionality of Texture projection with Node-Project.(Camera projection)